# Threshold based on sample size in each dataset in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, threshold

I want to create in R a threshold that is based on the sample size and will differ in each dataset. Let's say I have the following two datasets:

```
data<-matrix( rnorm(200*10,mean=0,sd=1), 200, 10) 
colnames(data) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")

data<-matrix( rnorm(100*10,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 10) 
colnames(data) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")
```

and I want to create a threshold that each time will differ and will be calculated based on the sample size. I want to code the following picture as a threshold, where on the left there are the threshold values, and on the right the sample size of each column(=n) [image]. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to take the number of rows your matrix and then choose a threshold.

One approach is to create a table with the sample sizes and thresholds. Then, given a sample size, filter the table so that the last row is the threshold and pull out that value.

```
# create table of thresholds
thresholds <- data.frame(n = c(50, 60, 70, 85), # etc
                         threshold = c(.75, .7, .65, .6) )

sample_size <- nrow(data)

tail(thresholds[thresholds$n <= sample_size, "threshold"], 1)
```

```
# Or if you're more comfortable with dplyr / tidyverse
thresholds <- tibble(n = c(50, 60, 70, 85), # etc
                         threshold = c(.75, .7, .65, .6) )
thresholds %>% 
   filter(n <= nrow(data)) %>%
   pull(threshold) %>%
   last()
```

If you plan on doing this with several data sets you can create a function:

```
get_threshold <- function(data, .thresholds = thresholds) {
   .thresholds %>% 
      filter(n <= nrow(data)) %>%
      pull(threshold) %>%
      last()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first two works perfectly for my purpose!